# Is storing pointer (of new'd object) in static collection from object constructor a common idiom in C++

Tags: c++

I am reviewing an approach I see commonly used in storing objects (e.g. a socket client object). Namely, usage of a static container to hold the objects. Said objects are created by some helper function as follows:

```
create_client(params) {
  ...
  client* cl = new client(...);
  return cl;
}
```

The thing that confused me at first was function called like this:

```
if (!create_client (...))
   //generate error message
```

i.e. a copy of the pointer just seems to be thrown away.

But on investigation I see this in the client constructor:

```
client::client(...) {
    ...
    coll[id] = this;
}
```

Where coll is a map of id to a pointer to the object. But anyway, just a collection.  coll is static (not sure if that is relevant).

Is there a name for this idiom?  Is it good practice?

Comment: In your second code block, did you mean `if (!create_client(...))`?

Comment: @DanPichelman - if not created correctly print error.  Its not important to question.

Comment: Dan means that you define the function as `client_create` and later use it as `create_client`.

Comment: Well spotted! I have edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not so familiar with C++, but I do not like the assignment into the static structure from the constructor, because:

1) Introduces a dependency: now the contained class needs to know about the containing instance. You cannot reuse the class without either rewritting or using the same structure.

2) It causes a reference leak from the constructor, since the reference to the class is available to other threads *before* the constructor has finished executing.

At the very least, I would have moved the instance assignment from the constructor to the `create_client` function.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a name for this idiom? Is it good practice?

No, and no, unless you count "Terrible" as an idiom name. There is no such thing as idiomatic mutable global state. Idioms exist to *avoid* such crap.

Comment: "Idioms exist to avoid such crap." Unless it's the singleton idiom (*cough*). Now where's the mouthwash?

Comment: Singleton is not an idiom. It is an idiot filter.

Answer (score 0):

This thing is called a [multiton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiton_pattern), so, yes, it *is* an idiom. It's not a good practice, though.